# How should I set up the equation for this problem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> A library leases its photocopier. One monthly bill was 750 dollars for
>   12,000 copies. Another month, the bill was $862.50 for 16,500 copies.
>   How much does the library pay for each copy?

How should I start set up the equation for this problem? 
How exactly do I find the linear equation giving the cost in terms of the number of copies used?

I am sorry if this is a stupid question, I am trying to review pre-calc and I forgot some techniques used to solve the problems.

Comment: The "slope" $ \ m \ $ of the line is the difference in the prices divided by the difference in the number of copies for the two bills you are given; this is the "price per copy".  You can then take either bill, use the price as $ \ y \ $ and the number of copies as $ \ x \ $ , and use this in the equation $ \ y \ = \ m \ x \ + \ b \ $ to find $ \ b \ $ which is the "base cost" that you pay to get copies at all.  (There are other approaches as well, but this is pretty direct.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the price per copy is a constant, then there is a linear relationship between the bill $B$ and the number of copies $n$, that is to say $$B=a + b\, n$$ If you have two data points $(n_1,B_1)$, $(n_2,B_2)$ you then have $$B_1=a+ b\, n_1$$ $$B_2=a+ b\, n_2$$ Subtract the first from the second to get $$B_2-B_1=b\,(n_2-n_1)$$ that is to say $$b=\frac{B_2-B_1}{n_2-n_1}$$ So, for the example $$b=\frac{862.5-750.0}{16500-12000}=\frac{112.5}{4500}=0.025$$ Now, you can use the first equation to get $a$ which is the fixed fee the library pays.

Answer (score 1):

By finding the difference in the prices and the difference in the number of copies we find that the second month, the library spent an additional \$112.50 for an additional 15,750 copies. Thus, we conclude that the library pays about 2.5 cents per copy, or .025 dollars per copy.

A linear equation has a slope and and a y-intercept. We already found the slope, it is the price per copy. The y-intercept is the amount the library pays for the copier each month as a base price, even if no copies are made. To do this, we simply subtract the cost of 12000 copies from the first month's cost. This is \$750-\$.0025$\times$12000=\$450.

Putting all the pieces together, the library pays \$450 every moth as a base cost, and then pays \$.025 for each copy made, so this comes to:
$$y=450+.025\times c,$$
where $y$ is the total cost and $c$ is the number of copies.

Answer (score 1):

The graph shows $P=(x_1, y_1)$ and $Q=(x_2, y_2)$, where $x$ is the number of copies and $y$ is the billed price.

It also shows the assumed linear relationship (red line) between price and and number of copies.

The price at $x=0$ (green line) is the fixed fee per month.

[image: copies]

The price per copy does not include that base price, it is that amount what is payed, if the number of copies is increased by one.
This is the slope $m$ of the line.

This assumes that the price per copy is fixed as well (no volume discounts etc).

Together this gives the linear equation:

$$
y = n + m x 
$$
where
$$
m = \frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}
$$
We can derive $n$, which is the price for $x=0$, thus the base price, by using one of the points, e.g the first one:
$$
y_1 = n + m x_1 \Rightarrow \\
n = y_1 - m x_1
$$